# How to make sure the picture loads on the recipent's end while sending an html email in outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

How do i send an html email in outlook 2016, and make sure that the pictures load on the recipients' end (as it is not loading and instead there is a box with red cross displaying). I have tried inserting as text-the html file, and sending it but the picture does not load in the recipient's end.

Answer (score 1):

Embedding images is done by inserting HTML containing `<img>` tags pointing to locally
available images, or by embedding a (small) base64-encoded image inline :

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" height="128" width="128" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD....snip..." />
```

However, many email clients block embedded images as a security measure, so that's not
the best way to send images.

A better way is to make the images available on your website, or alternatively
stored on a public server such as [imgur.com](https://imgur.com/).

The simplest test whether the email is readable, is to send it to yourself
on Outlook, or to another account such as Gmail.